# How to use .UseJwtBearerAuthentication in a OWIN asp.net project?

Tags: asp.net, api, authorization, owin, jwt

I'm converting a ASP.NetCore project to a stateless Web Api one. I was using the following to authenticate my JWT:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
        {
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                IssuerSigningKey = key,
                ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:5000",
                ValidAudience = "http://localhost:5000/resources",                            
                ValidateLifetime = true,

                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0)
            }
        });
```

And then Authorizing a controller using [Authorize("Bearer")]

However, I've noticed the OWIN project uses a different Authorize and Filters? I've not been able to successfully authorize my JWT using this and HostAuthentication.

Is this possible?